# Must the fulltext version of papers be in the same subdirectory as the html abstract to be indexed by Google Scholar?

Tags: directory, subdirectory, google-scholar

I have recently made an online repository of papers for an academic organisation. But we are not being picked up by Google Scholar. I think it might be because the fulltext urls are not in a format required by Google.

From [Google's Guidelines](https://www.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing):

> The "<meta>" tags normally apply only to the exact page on which they're provided. If this page shows only the abstract of the paper and you have the full text in a separate file, e.g., in the PDF format, please specify the locations of all full text versions using `citation_pdf_url` or DC.identifier tags. The content of the tag is the absolute URL of the PDF file; for security reasons, it must refer to a file in the same subdirectory as the HTML abstract.

The webiste is hosted on Microsoft Azure. The details of the papers with embedded metadata are of the form

```
http://iglc.net/Papers/Details/995
```

The full text version of the papers are served directly from Azure Storage, like this

```
https://iglcstorage.blob.core.windows.net/papers/attachment-1e0030fd-bc9e-4915-9a12-62088c387e8e.pdf
```

I am assuming this is not considered the same subdirectory. I sent a support ticket to Google Scholar two months ago and asked them to clarify, but I have so far gotten no response.

Anyhow, my questions are:

1. Am I correct in assuming that the fulltext must be placed in the same subdirectory?
2. What is considered the same subdirectory? Would serving up a fulltext from `/Papers/Details/990/Fulltext` be ok?

Answer (score 1):

Your subdirectory for `/Papers/Details/995` is `/Papers/Details/`.   So your suggestion of `/Papers/Details/990/Fulltext` should be fine.  So would `/Papers/Details/995.pdf`

Google almost never answers support tickets.   In this case, I think their documentation is pretty clear, and you need to move your pdf file to be included in Google Scholar.